# Stop async function in React component if component unmounts

Tags: javascript

Say I have a React component which has some async function, like a `setTimeOut` function which performs a task on the DOM element of that component. If the component unmounts during that `setTimeOut`, how would I prevent that async function from firing? The resulting function that fires throws an error since the DOM element no longer exists due to the component unmounting.

I'm attempting to ask a general question about theoretical ways to go about this, since I have quite a specific—but quite uncommon—use-case that essentially got no views in a previous question. The specific use-case that I have involves calling `destroy()` on a `pixi-react-fiber` graphics component after an animation completes, when sometimes the component has been unmounted during the animation. I think the general form of this question should be able to help me understand an approach.

edit: adding example

`Container.js`

```
const CursorContainer = props => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(props.darkMode)

  useEffect(() => {
    setDarkMode(props.darkMode)
  }, [props.darkMode])

  return (
    <Cursor darkMode={darkMode} />
  )
}

export default CursorContainer
```

`Cursor.js`

```
const TYPE = "Cursor"

export const behavior = {
  customDisplayObject: props => new PIXI.Graphics(),
  customApplyProps: function (g, _, props) {
    const { darkMode } = props
    g.clear()
    g.beginFill(darkMode ? 0x7225e6 : 0xd3fc03, 1)
    g.drawCircle(0, 0, 20)
    g.endFill()
    setTimeout(() => g.destroy(), 5000)
  },
}

const Cursor = CustomPIXIComponent(behavior, TYPE)

export default Cursor
```

If the `darkMode` is toggled, the `Cursor` component will be unmounted and remounted due to the state change. If this happens during the 5s `setTimeOut`, it will throw an error, since the `graphics` DOM element of the component will be gone and there will be nothing to destroy. How do I prevent this function from firing if the component has been unmounted?

Comment: May you share a [mcve] which shows the issue?

Comment: added example in edit

Answer (score 1):

Use a `ref` for maintaining a reference to the interval, and then clear the interval in the effect clean up callback -

e.g.

```
const Component = () => {
    const intervalRef = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {}, 1000);
        
        return () => {
            clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
        }
    }, [])
}
```

The use of `ref` will allow you to clear the timeout/interval from other handlers in the component

edit...

based on your response, if you were to update to the following, to return the timeout -

```
export const behavior = {
  customDisplayObject: props => new PIXI.Graphics(),
  customApplyProps: function (g, _, props) {
    const { darkMode } = props
    g.clear()
    g.beginFill(darkMode ? 0x7225e6 : 0xd3fc03, 1)
    g.drawCircle(0, 0, 20)
    g.endFill()
    return setTimeout(() => g.destroy(), 5000)
  },
}
```

then whereever in you `Cursor` component, that you have access to `customApplyProps` you could get the setTimeout reference from it, e.g.

```
intervalRef.current = customApplyProps();
```

then in an effect, clean it up in the return callback -

```
useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
    }
}, [])
```

Comment: On second thought, I probably did need a simple example of my use-case, since the component is not a function or class based react component, but a CustomPIXIComponent from react-pixi-fiber. You can see my edit in the OP.

Comment: depending on how you using `customApplyProps`, you could try changing the last line of that function to - `return setTimeout(() => g.destroy(), 5000)` so that whatever is calling it now has a ref to the timeout, then do as I have done above to clear the timeout when CustomPIXIComponent unmounts? e.g. `intervalRef.current = customApplyProps()` or whatever

Comment: Forgive my being dense but I'm not totally sure I understand. Are you saying that returning the setTimeOut would give ref access to the parent? Do you think you could edit your answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using function components, you can return a cleanup function in the `useEffect` hook that automatically gets called when the component unmounts. You can take the `clearTimeout` function that the `setTimeout` returns and call it in that cleanup function.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const timeout = setTimeout(..., ...);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: I've added a simplified example in my OP, the component is actually a CustomPIXIComponent which obviously does not allow hooks.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simpler approach here would be to lift the function up to a parent component which will not unmount. Then you can have a piece of state in the parent that controls whether the child component is rendered, and use that state as a logic gate when the function is invoked.

Comment: I'm not sure how I could lift the function to a parent component since it is a method of that specific CustomPIXIComponent... Unless I am misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: You don't have to lift the function. You can pass a call back function down to the props and then pass the g object to the function.
const { darkMode, parentCallBackDestory } = props ... 
setTimeout(() => parentCallBackDestory(g), 5000).
Your parent then has the "logic gate" in the parentCallBackDestory

Comment: Yes I see, what would be the best sort of logic gate in this situation. I'm reading that ```isMounted``` is antipattern according to react docs.

Comment: Trying to keep it simple, your CustomPIXIComponent needs to access to your "g" object. So when React component unmounts naturally in the unmounting step you can call g.destroy(). ...   

Not sure what your CustomPIXIComponent looks like, but if it's using a hook then in the return statement return () => { g.destroy() };  ....

The point is CustomPIXIComponent needs to handle when to destory g, not your customApplyProps function. This will avoid the antipattern.

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilaire situaton and this how I solved it :

```
const CursorContainer = props => {

  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(props.darkMode)

  useEffect(() => {
   let mounted= true; 
   if(mounted) setDarkMode(props.darkMode)
    return () => { mounted=false ; }
  }, [props.darkMode])

  return (
    <Cursor darkMode={darkMode} />
  )
}

export default CursorContainer
```